# Prove an inequality through convexity

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove $-hp + ln(1 - p + pe^h) \le (1/8)h^2$ for all $h > 0$ and $0 \le p \le 1$.

After moving the term $-hp$ to the RHS and exponentiating we get

$1 - p + pe^h \le e^{(1/8)h^2 + hp}$.

Now, for $p=0$ and $p=1$ we get,

$1 \le e^{(1/8)h^2 + h}$ and $e^h \le e^{(1/8)h^2 + h} \equiv 1 \le e^{(1/8)h^2}$.

Both of these inequalities obviously hold, so my question is can we claim from convexity that the exponentiated inequality holds for all $0 < p < 1$? Is there a specific property of convexity to cite in the proof?

Comment: when h is very small, it is not true from Wolfram when p = 0.5.

Comment: Could you provide an example? With p=0.5, h=1.0E-30, Wolfram gives 1 <= 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let: $$ \Phi (h) = -hp  + \ln (1-p+pe^h) $$

Then $$\Phi (h)' = -p + \frac {pe^h}{ 1-p+pe^h }$$
And: $$ \Phi (h)'' = \frac {pe^h (1-p) }{ (1-p+pe^h)^2 }  \le \frac {1}{4}$$

Since $ \Phi (0)= \Phi (0)' =0$ the result follows by Taylor series expansion.

EDIT:

Now we have, by Talyor expansion in zero with Lagrange rest: $$\Phi(u) = \Phi(0) + \Phi(0)'u + \Phi(\theta_u)''\frac{u^2}{2} \le \frac{1}{8}u^2$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the choice of 0 and how the result follows by Taylor series expansion? I understand that the second derivative of phi is greater than or equal to 0 for any h and thus phi is convex, but I'm unsure where Taylor series comes into play. Does the choice of zero have to do with a Taylor approximation with the Lagrangian remainder?

Comment: @NickMarton Yes, if comes from taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder. I edited the question adding this detail. I don't argue with convexity

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for the clarity!